# Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, excel-2010

I am trying to create program in .net using C# for uploading excel file, reading it and add record excel file to the sql server database from excel data. 
While doing so I have got an error: Could not find installable ISAM?

Can someone help me how to fix this problem?

Or may be provide some sample code to do such kind of assignment in different way?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String excelConnectionString1;
        String fname = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
        {
            String excelsheet;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/file/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
            {
                excelConnectionString1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/file/" + FileUpload1.FileName) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;";
                OleDbConnection myEcelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString1);
                myEcelConnection1.Open();
                if (txtsheet.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Please Write File Name";
                }
                else
                {
                    excelsheet = "[" + txtsheet.Text + "$" + "]";
                    string sheet = "Select * from [" + txtsheet.Text + "$" + "]";
                    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sheet, myEcelConnection1);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    DataSet myDataSet1 = new DataSet();
                    myAdapter1.Fill(myDataSet1);
                    int a = myDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1;
                    string name;
                    string dob;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
                    {
                        name = myDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        dob = myDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String for Sql Server");
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into info(name,dob)values(@valname,@valdob)", con);
                        command.Parameters.Add("@valname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@valdob", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = dob;
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code here? So that people can look what may be the problem.

Answer (score 6):

There's no 64 bit version of the Jet OLEDB drivers, so if you are running this on a 64 bit OS you might need to target x86 in your .NET application and not Any CPU.

**Or**

This error will also be generated when the syntax of the connection string is incorrect. This commonly occurs when using multiple Extended Properties parameters. Below is an example:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=e:\My Documents\Book20.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
```

Change connection string like this

```
ConnectionString=" Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\NAVEEN KUMAR\DOTNET\windows\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\123.xls;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"
```

Comment: I already tried to change the configuration to x86 but there is only the option of any cpu and even i couldn't add new target of x86.

Comment: Have you checked the second solution i have posted?

Comment: I checked the connection string and changed it a lot of times but still same problem arise...when I run the code it shows me error in:

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: I have added code in my question? can you please check it and help me to find the error ...Even you can suggest me if something is wrong